# Retained order from data.frame in boxplot

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame containing ordered data. When I plot it in the boxplot, it automatically sort by alphabetical order by boxplot.

Is there a way to retain the order in the data.frame in the plotting?

data.frame (ordered by Date) :

```
  Date       ID         Rate         Label
20131103    54232        98        54232 20131103
20131223    32123        94        32123 20131223
20140101    12345        89        12345 20140101
```

Boxplot :

```
boxplot(data_set$Rate ~ data_set$Label,
        data=data_set,
        col="yellow",
        main=Rate Trend,
        las=2, pch=0, outcol="red",
        par(mar = c(12, 5, 4, 2)+ 0.1))
```

Above code, automatically sort the data by ID instead of using the order in the data.frame.
Is there a way to retain the order in the data.frame in boxplot? I am using R v2.12.2.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is due to the order of the levels of the factor Label. One possibiliy:

```
with(data_set, boxplot(Rate ~ factor(Label, levels=unique(Label)), 
    col="yellow",
    main="Rate Trend",
    las=2, pch=0, outcol="red",
    par(mar = c(12, 5, 4, 2)+ 0.1)))
```

hth

Answer (score 2):

One simple way is to factorize the `Label`:

```
data_set$Label <- factor(data_set$Label,levels=unique(data_set$Label))
```

Then use your own code to plot!

```
boxplot(data_set$Rate ~ data_set$Label,
        data=data_set, col= "yellow", main="Rate Trend",
        las=2, pch=0, outcol="red",
        par(mar = c(12, 5, 4, 2)+ 0.1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Shambho and droopy are right, +1 - alternatively you might consider the `at`-parameter for a more fine-grained control over the positionings (also note the `ToothGrowth` example at the bottom of `?boxplot`):

```
with(iris[nrow(iris):1,], 
  boxplot(Sepal.Length ~ Species,at=order(unique(Species))))
```